# simple string Extension method causes compiler error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I have the following class in a folder called Helpers in a simple MVC4 application:

```
namespace MyFirstMVC4.Helpers
{
    public static class Sample
    {

        public static int WordCount(this string str)
        {
            return str.Split(new char[] { ' ', '.', '?' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
        }
    }
}
```

I then have the following code in a controller:

```
using MyFirstMVC4.Helpers;
int x = "1 2 3 4".WordCount();
```

The compiler throws an error saying name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'MyFirstMVC4'.

If I removed the using  MyFirstMVC4.Helpers statement the compiler throws an error saying string does not have a definition for WordCount

**The Sample class, copied exactly the same as it is in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application works fine in a console application**.

Comment: FYI, compiler errors are unlikely to depend on MVC4. You'd get the same error with or without MVC4.

Comment: You should never use a namespace belonging to someone else without their permission. I strongly recommend you use your own namespace for that. Still, the problem has nothing to do with MVC4, per se.

Comment: I have the Sample class exactly as written in my question in a Console application and the it compiles and works correct.

Comment: MVC is not a compiler. It doesn't "compile static classes". It's the same compiler and same language rules used in both.  Are you using a Web Site "project" (File->Add New Web Site)? You shouldn't those do strange things with namespaces.

Comment: I know MVC is not a compiler. Even the worst developer in the world would know MVC is not a compiler. I was just simplifying my explanation of the issue. The issue was clearly a bug in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The exact same code worked in a ConsoleApp but not my MVC4 project so that is why I chose to use the wording "MVC compiles". But unless English was not your first language and/or you didn't clearly read my question you would have noticed that I didn't start saying "MVC compiles", I built up to that lingo be clearly stating that the ConsoleApp was compiling with the exact same static class.

I am 100% confident that you knew that I knew that MVC was not a compiler. It would be better for you and everyone else if you try not to be condescending.

Comment: If you know it's not a compiler, then don't say that it compiles. If you meant "the MVC scenario compiles", then say that. And, no, I didn't _know_ that you knew it was not a compiler. It shocks me to see the extent to which some people juxtapose unrelated ideas these days, especially in a world in which we can say things like "ASP.NET compiles your pages to C# code which is compiled to IL, which is Just in Time compiled to machine code".

Comment: BTW, you never answered: is the MVC application a web site "project", or is it a web application project?

Comment: Sorry for not replying previously John, my answer had been deleted and it seemed the question was disabled for further follow up. My project is a ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application. I have provided the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Extension methods must have the namespace declared.

Assuming your "Sample" class is in the "Foo.Bar" namespace, you need to go

```
using Foo.Bar;
```

This is the word count extension I'm using:

```
namespace Core.BaseLibrary.Extensions
{
    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a count of words in the passed string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stringToCount">The string to count.</param>
        /// <returns>An integer containing the number of words in the string</returns>
        public static int WordCount(this string stringToCount)
        {
            return Regex.Matches(stringToCount, @"[\S]+").Count;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is how I'm using it:

```
using Core.BaseLibrary.Extensions;
int wordCount = value.ToString().WordCount();
```

but

```
int wc = "1 2 3 4 5".WordCount();
```

also works.

So in other words, it looks like syntactically you are doing everything right.

Comment: I have added the namespace to my controller class and I am getting a compiler error saying that the namespace Helpers does not exist. I have edited my question so that you can see the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. Two caveats: One, I restarted Visual Studio 2012 and this did not fix my issue. And two, this bug just happened to me again with another class that was syntactically correct and previously compiling fine. The bug seems to have something to do with moving a previously compiling class to a new directory in Visual Studio 2012.

The fix is simply to delete the class file and then add the class again to your solution. This will fix the compiler error.

Comment: Ok, I don't remember how to find it, but I suggest when this happens you find the ASP.NET "temporary files" and purge it. There may be an old version of the file in the cache.